# Generate a payment schedule and calculate a running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am looking to build a T-SQL stored procedure that displays payment schedules and maintains a running total of payments made.  I'm getting rows for which there are payments, but I need to display all rows, regardless of whether payments have been made or not.  The main tables are

- **PaymentPlan** - The "parent" record
- **PaymentPlanSchedule** - Maintains the schedule dates for payments, amounts due, etc.
- **PaymentPlanPayment** - Actually stores payments that have been made.

I am using the `Over ()` clause to generate the running total.  How can I modify this query to return scheduled payments that have not yet been made?  Here is my logic:
Thanks!

```
SELECT pp.PApKey, pps.PPSScheduleDate AS ScheduledDate, pps.PPSScheduleAmount AS ScheduledAmount, ppp.PPPAmount AS PaidAmount, 
    SUM(ppp.PPPAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY pp.PApKey ORDER BY pps.PPSScheduleDate) AS PaymentTotal
FROM
    LawFirm lf INNER JOIN MgmtCo mc ON mc.LFpKey = lf.LFpKey
    INNER JOIN Assoc a ON mc.MCpKey = a.MCpKey
    INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.ASpKey = a.ASpKey
    INNER JOIN PaymentPlan pp ON pp.CApKey = c.CApKey
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanSchedule pps ON pps.PApKey = pp.PApKey
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanPayments ppp ON pps.PPSpKey = ppp.PPSpKey
WHERE lf.LFpKey = @LFpKey
    AND mc.MCpKey = @MCpKey
    AND a.ASpKey = @ASpKey
    AND c.CAActive = 1
    AND pp.PAActive = 1
    AND pps.PPSActive = 1
    AND ppp.PPPActive = 1
```

Comment: We really need sample data and expected results here. We don't have enough information to tell you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I can appreciate that.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to format results in a readable tabular format that will maintain its format in the question.

Comment: Data is best presented and DDL and DML statement, @Mike, or formatted tabular `text` (the former would be far better

Comment: Try this link [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to make two assumptions here, in hope they are an educated guess that might help you: 
 
1. That unpaid cases are accounted in the running total with the amount of 0. 
2. That all of unpaid cases are the ones that are present in PaymentPlanSchedule, but not in the PaymentPlanPayments. 
 
Given these two assumptions hold, the solution would be: 
 
1. Create a cte unpaid that holds all the unpaid cases. 
2. Another cte allpaid_and_unpaid that now makes the union of PaymentPlanPayments and unpaid, PaymentPlanPayments keep their original amount, whilst unpaid default to 0. 
3. In your query, use this allpaid_and_unpaid in place of PaymentPlanPayments.

```
with unpaid as
(
select 
pp.PApKey, 
pps.PPSScheduleDate AS ScheduledDate,
pps.PPSScheduleAmount AS ScheduledAmount,
0 AS PaidAmount
from 
LawFirm lf INNER JOIN MgmtCo mc ON mc.LFpKey = lf.LFpKey
INNER JOIN Assoc a ON mc.MCpKey = a.MCpKey
INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.ASpKey = a.ASpKey
INNER JOIN PaymentPlan pp ON pp.CApKey = c.CApKey
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanSchedule pps ON pps.PApKey = pp.PApKey
where
lf.LFpKey = @LFpKey
AND mc.MCpKey = @MCpKey
AND a.ASpKey = @ASpKey
AND c.CAActive = 1
AND pp.PAActive = 1
AND pps.PPSActive = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT * from PaymentPlanPayments ppp where pps.PPSpKey = ppp.PPSpKey AND 
 ppp.PPPActive = 1)
),
allpaid_and_unpaid as 
(
SELECT pp.PApKey, 
pps.PPSScheduleDate AS ScheduledDate,
pps.PPSScheduleAmount AS ScheduledAmount,
ppp.PPPAmount AS PaidAmount, 
FROM
  LawFirm lf INNER JOIN MgmtCo mc ON mc.LFpKey = lf.LFpKey
  INNER JOIN Assoc a ON mc.MCpKey = a.MCpKey
  INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.ASpKey = a.ASpKey
  INNER JOIN PaymentPlan pp ON pp.CApKey = c.CApKey
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanSchedule pps ON pps.PApKey = pp.PApKey
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanPayments ppp ON pps.PPSpKey = ppp.PPSpKey
WHERE lf.LFpKey = @LFpKey
  AND mc.MCpKey = @MCpKey
  AND a.ASpKey = @ASpKey
  AND c.CAActive = 1
  AND pp.PAActive = 1
  AND pps.PPSActive = 1
  AND ppp.PPPActive = 1

UNION

SELECT * FROM unpaid

)
SELECT PApKey, 
ScheduledDate,
ScheduledAmount,
PaidAmount, 
SUM(PaidAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY PApKey ORDER BY ScheduleDate) AS PaymentTotal
FROM
allpaid_and_unpaid
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting filter using `where` clause on the outer joined tables, therefore, SQL Server will make it like an inner join.

[image: Showing move where part in join]

```
SELECT pp.PApKey, pps.PPSScheduleDate AS ScheduledDate, pps.PPSScheduleAmount AS 
       ScheduledAmount, ppp.PPPAmount AS PaidAmount, 
       SUM(ppp.PPPAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY pp.PApKey ORDER BY pps.PPSScheduleDate) AS PaymentTotal
FROM
       LawFirm lf INNER JOIN MgmtCo mc ON mc.LFpKey = lf.LFpKey
       INNER JOIN Assoc a ON mc.MCpKey = a.MCpKey
       INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.ASpKey = a.ASpKey
       INNER JOIN PaymentPlan pp ON pp.CApKey = c.CApKey
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanSchedule pps ON pps.PApKey = pp.PApKey
                                                   and pp.PAActive = 1
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN PaymentPlanPayments ppp ON pps.PPSpKey = ppp.PPSpKey
                                                   and pps.PPSActive = 1
 WHERE lf.LFpKey = @LFpKey
       AND mc.MCpKey = @MCpKey
       AND a.ASpKey = @ASpKey
       AND c.CAActive = 1
       --AND pp.PAActive = 1
       --AND pps.PPSActive = 1
       --AND ppp.PPPActive = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your consideration!  I tried your suggestion and got the same result, only records that have a value for PaymentPlanPayments.